# Include signature (.mli) file in library

Tags: interface, ocaml, libraries, signature, ocamlbuild

I have a library were the common datatypes are defined in a signature-only module (copying that signature to an implementation does not make sense, since it does not contain any functionality):

```
(* b.mli *)
type bar = A of int | B of float

(* a.ml: *)
let foo = function B.A i -> B.A (i+1)
                 | B.B f -> B.B (f +. 1.)

(* c.mllib *)
A
B
```

In the setup above, ocamlbuild fails to create the library with a rather surprising error:

```
choeger@daishi /tmp/test % ocamlbuild c.cmxa
Solver failed:
  Ocamlbuild cannot find or build c.ml.  A file with such a name would usually be a source file.  I suspect you have given a wrong target name to Ocamlbuild.
```

I can build without specifying B inside the mllib file, but then the type bar becomes abstract (which is not intended). Is there any way to include the *signature* using ocamlbuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pack `B` module into the library because it doesn't exist. You have only compiled interface, but not a compiled module, i.e., a compilation unit. The purpose of the `cmxa` is to be a container for a compiled code, since your `B` interface doesn't contain any code nothing can be put into the library. That means, that you do not need at all to put the reference to the module B into the `mllib` file.

A more common approach is to put types and interfaces into the `ml` file without a `mli` one. I think that this approach is better in comparison to `mli` only approach, because it allows one to use type-driven code generators, for example, with `mli` only approach you can't do the following:

```
type bar = A of int | B of float with sexp
```

But, if you still want to have a `mli` without an `ml` then I would suggest you to use `oasis`. It has a feature called `pure_interface`, that allows you to build such libraries.

Comment: That makes more sense. One probably shouldn't get used to using pack since it doesn't support module alias.